# jquery not working after resize div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is a jquery to auto resize text according to `#outer` div width and height okay. If i change `#outer` div width and height manually before render HTML then its fitting text  (auto resizing text) properly to `#outer` div. Just Like see in Example 1 and Example 2 its fitting text.

**Example-1**

```js
 $.fn.fitInText = function() {
  this.each(function() {

    let textbox = $(this);
    let textboxNode = this;

    let mutationCallback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
      if (observer) {
        observer.disconnect();
      }
      textbox.css('font-size', 0);
      let desiredHeight = textbox.css('height');
      for (i = 12; i < 50; i++) {
        textbox.css('font-size', i);
        if (textbox.css('height') > desiredHeight) {
          textbox.css('font-size', i - 1);
          break;
        }
      }

      var config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true
      };
      let newobserver = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
      newobserver.observe(textboxNode, config);

    };

    mutationCallback();

  });
}

$('#inner').fitInText();
```

```css
#outer {
  display: table;
  width: 500px;
   height: 300px;
   transition: width 1s;
}

#inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner" contenteditable=true>
          We think the Spirit working through the Word, not an expert at the head of the classroom, is essential to discipleship. When we begin here we learn “how to think biblically”. Our focus is less on answering questions you don’t have and more on helping you learn how to find the answers within thes is less on answering questions you don’t have and mos is less on answering questions you don’t have and more on helping you learn how to find the answers within the Bible. We must seek Jesus in the Bible, trusting that God has the answers. This means learning patichurch leadership, but we are available to supply coaches to be to answer questions or suggest next areas to study based on their questions.

  </div>
</div>
```

**Example-2 with increased `#outer` div width and height, its still working to fit text into `#outer`**

```js
 $.fn.fitInText = function() {
  this.each(function() {

    let textbox = $(this);
    let textboxNode = this;

    let mutationCallback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
      if (observer) {
        observer.disconnect();
      }
      textbox.css('font-size', 0);
      let desiredHeight = textbox.css('height');
      for (i = 12; i < 50; i++) {
        textbox.css('font-size', i);
        if (textbox.css('height') > desiredHeight) {
          textbox.css('font-size', i - 1);
          break;
        }
      }

      var config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true
      };
      let newobserver = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
      newobserver.observe(textboxNode, config);

    };

    mutationCallback();

  });
}

$('#inner').fitInText();
```

```css
#outer {
  display: table;
  width: 700px;
   height: 400px;
   transition: width 1s;
}

#inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner" contenteditable=true>
          We think the Spirit working through the Word, not an expert at the head of the classroom, is essential to discipleship. When we begin here we learn “how to think biblically”. Our focus is less on answering questions you don’t have and more on helping you learn how to find the answers within thes is less on answering questions you don’t have and mos is less on answering questions you don’t have and more on helping you learn how to find the answers within the Bible. We must seek Jesus in the Bible, trusting that God has the answers. This means learning patichurch leadership, but we are available to supply coaches to be to answer questions or suggest next areas to study based on their questions.

  </div>
</div>
```

But if i change `#outer` div width and height ratio from Jquery `onclick` button then its not changing text font size again and not fitting text to div.

means i want making change `#outer` div width and height through `button` then it should be working Like see Example 3, Although i added `onclick="fitInText()"` to button. . i want to make work it with **example 3 situation.**

> **After click on button just add any letter, space in  `#outer` div content and see magic.**

```js
$.fn.fitInText = function() {
  this.each(function() {

    let textbox = $(this);
    let textboxNode = this;

    let mutationCallback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
      if (observer) {
        observer.disconnect();
      }
      textbox.css('font-size', 0);
      let desiredHeight = textbox.css('height');
      for (i = 12; i < 50; i++) {
        textbox.css('font-size', i);
        if (textbox.css('height') > desiredHeight) {
          textbox.css('font-size', i - 1);
          break;
        }
      }

      var config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true
      };
      let newobserver = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
      newobserver.observe(textboxNode, config);

    };

    mutationCallback();

  });
}

$('#inner').fitInText();



//Jquery for change outer div width
$('.newsize').on('click', function() {
    $('#outer').toggleClass('newouter');
});
```

```css
#outer {
  display: table;
  width: 500px;
   height: 300px;
   transition: width 1s;
}

#outer.newouter {
  display: table;
  width: 700px;
   height: 400px;
}

#inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <button class="newsize" onclick="fitInText()"> Change Width Height </button>
    
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner" contenteditable=true>
          We think the Spirit working through the Word, not an expert at the head of the classroom, is essential to discipleship. When we begin here we learn “how to think biblically”. Our focus is less on answering questions you don’t have and more on helping you learn how to find the answers within thes is less on answering questions you don’t have and mos is less on answering questions you don’t have and more on helping you learn how to find the answers within the Bible. We must seek Jesus in the Bible, trusting that God has the answers. This means learning patichurch leadership, but we are available to supply coaches to be to answer questions or suggest next areas to study based on their questions.

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `fitInText function not defined`

Comment: The mutation observer is watching `inner`, but you're changing the class of `outer`. So the callback function is never called when you change the DIV width.

Comment: Hay, #Barmar can you tell me then what a solution for that

Answer (score 0):

I removed the font resizing script and changed the font size instead with transition when changing the length and width

this code

```
#outer {
   display: table;
   width: 500px;
   height: 300px;
   transition: all 1s;
}

#outer.newouter {
   display: table;
   width: 700px;
   height: 400px;
}
```

I changed it with this code

```
#outer {
  display: table;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all 1.5s;
}

#outer.newouter {
   display: table;
   width: 700px;
   height: 400px;
   font-size: 48px;
}
```

complete code:

```js
    //Jquery for change outer div width
    $('.newsize').on('click', function() {
        $('#outer').toggleClass('newouter');
    });
```

```css
    #outer {
      display: table;
      width: 500px;
      height: 300px;
      
       font-size: 18px;
       transition: all 1.5s;
    }

    #outer.newouter {
      display: table;
      width: 700px;
      height: 400px;
       font-size: 48px;
    }

    #inner {
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 170px;
      text-align: center;
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      word-break: break-all;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <button class="newsize"> Change Width Height </button>
        
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner" contenteditable=true>
              We think the Spirit working through the Word, not an expert at the head of the classroom, is essential to discipleship. When we begin here we learn “how to think biblically”. Our focus is less on answering questions you don’t have and more on helping you learn how to find the answers within thes is less on answering questions you don’t have and mos is less on answering questions you don’t have and more on helping you learn how to find the answers within the Bible. We must seek Jesus in the Bible, trusting that God has the answers. This means learning patichurch leadership, but we are available to supply coaches to be to answer questions or suggest next areas to study based on their questions.

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hay ! meysam asadi, can you share example code plz...

Comment: because after that the script is banning page to use, its just like crash the page.

Comment: I modified your code. Your code did not work. It works now. Now see if it works for you

Comment: Yes, the code hangs. I changed the code. Now, if you change it a little yourself, I think the problem will be solved.

Comment: you made some change. Thanks for it but not working perfectly 

plz check this code may be you can right that by some change: https://codepen.io/rksbhl/pen/KKNPyEP

Comment: Hay !  meysam asadi , plz check it :    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65933404/how-can-i-animate-this-jquery-style-change-new-problem-facing

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.